# Visual Studio - Windows UI Library - set TargetPlatformMinVersion and TargetPlatformVersion (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to try the Windows UI Library in Visual Studio. I have followed the installation instructions from Microsoft (Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started). Unfortunately I can't find the place where I can set the "TargetPlatformMinVersion" and the "TargetPlatformVersion".

I found this picture, but I cannot find these settings.

[image: Screenshot Projectsettings]

If I skip this step, I unfortunately get an error message.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Approach:

Please follow the instruction of how to change TargetplatformVersion:

1) Right-click on your project in Visual Studio

2) Select `“Unload Project“`, it will now appear as ProjectName `(unavailable)`

3) Right-click on the unloaded project and select `“Edit projectName.csproj”`

4) Locate the `<TargetPlatformVersion>` and `<TargetPlatformMinVersion>` items in the first `<PropertyGroup>`.

5) Change the `TargetPlatformMinVersion` to the version that you want.

6) Now Save and Close the file

7) Select the “Load Project“ to Launch the project again.

**Second Approach:**

1) Close Your project in visual studio

2) Open Your `projectName.csproj` with Notepad or Notepad++

4) Locate the `<TargetPlatformVersion>` and `<TargetPlatformMinVersion>` items in the first `<PropertyGroup>`.

5) Change the `TargetPlatformMinVersion` to the version that you want.

6) Now Save and Close the file

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have adopted the settings, unfortunately I now get the message that XamlControlsResources cannot be found. Do you have an idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Your welcome my friend, maybe one of your packages is not installed correctly or not matched with the current version of your app. Please provide more detail for a better solution.

Comment: Sorry if any information is missing. This is my first time working with C# and I am not sure what information you need.
Microsoft UI Version 2.4.2; target framework .Net Core 3.1
All error messages
The name "XamlControlsResource is not available in the namespace "...".
Each directory entry must have an assigned key.
Type XamlControlsResources was not found. Make sure that no assembly reference is missing and that all referenced assemblies were created.
The tag "XamlControlsResources" is not present in the XML namespace "using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls".

Comment: I think your App.xaml is not set correctly, please set "XamlControlsResources" as your Application resources. -> <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have tried a few things, but I have not come to a result. I have set the app.xaml to Git. Could you take a quick look at it there?
https://github.com/A456B123/WindowsUIAppXaml/blob/master/App.xaml

Comment: It look like correct to me, so please check the steps in this document, maybe it would help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started