# How to fix TargetPlatformMinVersion problem in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, winui

I'm trying to use [Windows UI library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/) in my WPF app, and whenever I install `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` I get the following error.

> Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package requires TargetPlatformMinVersion >= 10.0.15063.0 (current project is -1)

How to resolve this issue?

My windows SDK version is the latest version downloaded from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/).

My OS version is 20H2 and the build number is 19042.685

I tried changing the targeted framework from .NET Core 3, 3.1, and .NET 5.

*[If you think the title of this question is not appropriate, feel free to suggest an edit.]*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62128558/visual-studio-windows-ui-library-set-targetplatformminversion-and-targetplat

Comment: How followed the steps and noticed that there were no properties called `<TargetPlatformVersion>` or `<TargetPlatformMinVersion>`. So I added them manually and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post your reproducing project on the web somewhere?

Comment: You mean the full source code?

Comment: I can install the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` in my .Net core 3.1 WPF project with no error. If you upload the project to reproduce the error, it will help to analyze your problem more accurately.

Comment: https://github.com/MahmudX/AwesomeWPF here is the full project

Comment: Adding  `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` and 
`<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.15063.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>` to your csproj file will make your project run with no error. It refers to [Download and install the Windows UI Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started#download-and-install-the-windows-ui-library). As fa as I know it is design for UWP not WPF, could you tell me what api or class do you want to use in WPF?

Comment: The new Fluent design API. It looks awesome but the default WPF UI looks terrible.

Comment: Did my suggestion work for your issue? If it is not, please let me what error did you meet.

Comment: No, it didn't. I got the same error. IDK what went wrong. Sorry for my late reply. I went busy with my office project.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using VS 2022. I think it's a bug.
[Possible Failure of Target Platform detection](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3596)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem transferring my project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 (needed to have "using declarations").

Here's how I fixed mine:

1. Go to the affected project's settings.
2. Go to General and Target OS version.
3. Choose 1.0.19041.0 (or at the very least it must be 10.0.18362.0)
4. In the Supported OS version, choose any version except 7.0 or 8.0.
5. Build the project.

I think (I'm not sure) the issue here is UI.Xaml doesn't support Win 7 or Win 8.